# Prove that 11 divides a if and only if 11 divides the alternating sum of the digits of a

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

Been stuck in this problem for quite a  while. Apparently uses modular congruence to solve.

Comment: $10\equiv -1\mod 11$, so $10^n\equiv(-1)^n\mod 11$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $a = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n10^n$ mod 11. Then as $10\equiv -1\mod 11$ we have

> $$a\equiv\sum_{n=0}^Na_n(-1)^n\mod 11$$

which is exactly the alternating sum of its digits. If this is $0$, then by definition that's divisibility by $11$. This actually shows a stronger fact, not only is $a$ divisible by $11$ iff its alternating digital sum is, but in fact $a$ is always congruent to the alternating sum of its digits, be that sum $0$ or otherwise.

Comment: Students should *beware* that such substitutions of an integer by a congruent integer are not generally valid. The reason they are valid above is because the expression is a composition of sums and products, and those operations enjoy this property due to the [Congruence Sum and Product Rules.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) Generally this fails for other types of operations, e.g. powers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ Radix notation has *Polynomial* form $\,n = d_0\! + d_1 10 + d_2 10^2\! +\cdots + d_k 10^k\! = P(10)\,$ so

${\rm mod}\ 11\!:\ \color{#c00}{10}\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\,\Rightarrow\ n = P(\color{#c00}{10}) \equiv P(\color{#c00}{-1}) \equiv d_0 - d_1  + d_2 - \cdots + (-1)^k d_k\, $ by applying the [Polynomial Congruence Rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) i.e. $\,a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\,P(a)\equiv P(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$10 \equiv -1  \mod 11$$

$$123=1 \times 10^2 + 2 \times 10 +3$$